# implement CVE-2017-7494 (samba cry) on ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: security, compilation, samba, ubuntu-server

Recently my experiment needs to implement CVE-2017-7494 (the so called sambacry), and I am trying to rebuild the vulnerable environment

I am new to this, not very sure how to set all the path and conf right

here is what I did:

```
# wget https://download.samba.org/pub/samba/stable/samba-4.5.9.tar.gz
# apt-get install acl attr autoconf bison build-essential \
  debhelper dnsutils docbook-xml docbook-xsl flex gdb krb5-user \
  libacl1-dev libaio-dev libattr1-dev libblkid-dev libbsd-dev \
  libcap-dev libcups2-dev libgnutls-dev libjson-perl \
  libldap2-dev libncurses5-dev libpam0g-dev libparse-yapp-perl \
  libpopt-dev libreadline-dev perl perl-modules pkg-config \
  python-all-dev python-dev python-dnspython python-crypto \
  xsltproc zlib1g-dev
```

[Reference about the above package](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Package_Dependencies_Required_to_Build_Samba).

```
# tar -xvf samba-4.5.9.tar.gz
# cd samba-4.5.9
# ./configure
# make
# make install
```

after that I found it installed under /local, and cannot start samba normally because, say, smbd not found, etc

I think it's a problem of path and config file then [I tried this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/samba.html) to fix it.

But didn't get well realizing.

Would anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify a path in your configure parameters, it should be by default at `/usr/local/samba/sbin/smbd`.

You can try running this in your shell (and add it to your profile) to add it to your path:

`export PATH=/usr/local/samba/bin/:/usr/local/samba/sbin/:$PATH`

Comment: ah.... that do add the binaries to environment variable,  
but I still can't start smbd and nmbd as daemon and start the samba servie
,  or I missed something?

Comment: also I can't use systemctl to control samba

Comment: ah,  sorry, I found it,  thank you still,  for answering a newbie like me